# Prevent SQL injection for queries that combine the query builder with DB::raw()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4, I want to protect some complex database queries from SQL injection. These queries use a combination of the query builder and DB::raw(). Here is a simplified example:

```
$field = 'email';
$user = DB::table('users')->select(DB::raw("$field as foo"))->whereId(1)->get();
```

I've read [Chris Fidao's tutorial](http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries) that it is possible to pass an array of bindings to the select() method, and therefore prevent SQL injection correctly, by using prepared statements. For example:

```
$results = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT :field FROM users WHERE id=1"), 
               ['field' => $field]
           ));
```

This works, but the example puts the entire query into a raw statement. It doesn't combine the query builder with DB::raw(). When I try something similar using the first example:

```
$field = 'email';
$user = DB::table('users')->select(DB::raw("$field as foo"), ['field' => $field])
             ->whereId(1)->get();
```

... then I get an error: **strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given**

*What is the correct way to prevent SQL injection for queries that combine the query builder with DB::raw()?*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I discovered the query builder has a method called **setBindings()** that can be useful in this instance:

```
$field = 'email';
$id = 1;
$user = DB::table('users')->select(DB::raw(":field as foo"))
        ->addSelect('email')
        ->whereId(DB::raw(":id"))
        ->setBindings(['field' => $field, 'id' => $id])
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

Eloquent uses PDO under the hood to sanitize items. It won't sanitize items added to SELECT statements.

The [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) method is still useful for sanitizing SQL strings, however.

Consider also (or instead) keeping an array of valid field names from the users table and checking against that to ensure there isn't an invalid value being used.

```
$allowedFields = ['username', 'created_at'];

if( ! in_array($field, $allowedFields) )
{
    throw new \Exception('Given field not allowed or invalid');
}

$user = DB::table('users')
            ->select(DB::raw("$field as foo"))
            ->whereId(1)->get();
```

Comment: thanks. I had hoped to be able to still use prepared statements, but mysqli_real_escape_string will work. I think it would be great if the Laravel documentation could show the recommended way to prevent SQL injection for raw queries, instead of just warning about the risk.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to being able to use `setBindings()` as a standalone function with `DB::raw`, all of the Query Builder's new "raw methods" - `selectRaw`, `whereRaw`, `havingRaw`, etc. - accept an array of bindings as their second argument. Although not explicitly mentioned in the [relevant documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#raw-methods), I managed to figure out this basically means you need to replace your valuable SQL variables with a question mark and then place the value of these variables into the array:

```
$user = DB::table('users')->selectWhere("? as permissions", [admin]))->get(); 
// This will replace ? with admin
```

In doing so this prevents exposing your variables, preventing them from being SQL injected and manipulated.