# Secure laravel query which use DB::Raw

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I'm really new in Laravel and I'm not sure how can I secure from `SQL Injections` query which use `DB::Raw`. I have read trough [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#raw-expressions) and I've read that is kind of insecure and should be secured since it's injected in the query as a string...

> These expressions will be injected into the query as strings, so be careful not to create any SQL injection points

Myquery looks like this

```
DB::table('sub_category as sc')
    ->leftJoin('products as p', 'p.sub_cat_id', '=', 'sc.sub_cat_id')
    ->where('sc.category_id', '=', $categoryId)
    ->whereNotNull('p.sub_cat_id')
    ->select('p.*','sc.*', DB::raw('sc.sub_cat_id AS sub_cat_id'))
    ->groupBy('sc.sub_cat_id')
    ->get();
```

The query simply display on page only categories which have products in it.

Comment: The db:raw() call does not use any user provided input, so it is safe from sql injection.

Comment: So like in php I just need to worry and secure queries only on user inputs, forms .. etc? For the rest Laravel wil ltake care since is using PDO, right?

Comment: It depends on if laravel uses prepared statements with pdo or not. I do not know laravel, so cannot help you with that. Probably a quick google search will confirm this for you.

Comment: It's on their documentation.. same link which I've posted with the question: `Note: The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding throughout to protect your application against SQL injection attacks. There is no need to clean strings being passed as bindings.`. Okay thank's.

Comment: Please use this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26670933/prevent-sql-injection-for-queries-that-combine-the-query-builder-with-dbraw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sql injection risk comes -mainly and usually- if there is data sent through  **$_GET['foo']** or **$_POST['bar']** from a web user.  You should protect your database from SQL injections by binding data to the raw query as shown:

```
$risky_input=$_GET['some_risky_input'];//assuming this comes from an input field
$result=
DB::select(
    DB::raw("SELECT * FROM category WHERE category_name=:queriedterm ")
    ,['queriedterm'=>$risky_input]//binds data throuhg array
    )
;
```

Please notice the colon ":" and variable next to it.  This will protect your query from sql injections.

Note: Your query doesn't have any slq injection risk since it doesn't contain parameters from any text input field filled by a web user.